# How to design a database for efficient search-ability?

Tags: sql, search, database-design

I am trying to design a database with search-ability at its core. My knowledge of database design and SQL is all self-taught and still fairly beginner-level, so my questions may possibly have easy answers.

Suppose I have a single table containing a large number of records. For example, suppose that each record contains details of a different computer application (name, developer, version number, etc). A list of keywords are associated with each record, such as a list of programming languages used to write the applications.

I wish to be able to enter one or more keywords (each separated by a space) into a search box, and I wish to have all associated records returned. How should I design the database to store the keywords, and what SQL query would I need to apply to the search text? (The search should be uppercase/lowercase independent.)

My next challenge would then be to order search results by relevance, and to allow entire key-phrases as well as keywords to be associated with each record. For example, if I type "Visual Basic" into the search field, I want the first results to have exactly the key-phrase "Visual Basic" associated with them. The next results should all have both keywords "Visual" and "Basic" associated with them, and the remaining results should have only one of these keywords. Again, please could anyone advise on how to implement this?

The final challenge I believe would be much harder: how much 'intelligent interpretation' can I design my database and SQL code to handle? For example, if I search for "CSS", can I get the records with the key-phrase "Cascading Style Sheets" to appear? Can I also get SQL to identify and search for similar words, such as plurals of search phrases or, for example, "programmer" or "programming" when "program" is input? Thanks!

Comment: you may want to read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Added point: I'm anticipating a many-to-many relationship between the applications and the 'programming technologies' key-phrases.

Comment: @Ankit Thanks, but I understand normalisation already. I realise that I could have a table of key-phrases joined to the table of applications, but my questions lean more towards the search features of this setup.

Comment: Are your "keywords" predetermined? I.e. do you have an exact list of fields you need to search on (name, developer, version number, etc.), or these fields can be added at run-time by users?

Comment: @Branko Keywords can be added by users at run-time. Thanks for your interest, but I think I've found a solution (see my answer below).

Answer (score 4):

Learn relational algebra, normalization rules, and SQL.

Start with entity relationships.  Sounds like you could have an APPLICATION table as parent for a FEATURE child table, with a one-to-many relationship between the two.  You'll query them by JOINing one to the other:

```
SELECT A.NAME, F.NAME
FROM APPLICATION AS A 
JOIN FEATURE AS F
ON F.APP_ID = A.ID
```

Your challenges would not suggest SQL and relations to me.  I would think more in terms of a parser, an indexer and search engine like Lucene, and a NoSQL document database like MongoDB.

Comment: Thanks. I've just looked up Lucene and it certainly looks like it might do the trick. Just a few questions though:
Why would I need to use a NoSQL database over a SQL database, if I don't proceed to use any SQL code and instead use a search engine? (I have never worked with NoSQL).
What is meant by the parser and indexer in this context?
Why also would relations not be appropriate for this? Relational database design is the only database design I know of... what is the alternative design?

Comment: You need to read more than a quick lookup for Lucene.  I can't reproduce all the info you need in answers or comments.  I've already given you some good ideas to chase down: documents, indexers, NoSQL.

Comment: Of course. NoSQL is fine - I can look that up. The other phrases (documents, indexers, parsers) have broader meanings and are harder to look-up, especially when I'm not so sure precisely what I'm looking for. Could you offer some narrower phrases I could look up please?

Comment: Lucene, dude.  Isn't that narrow enough for you?  And do you not know what documents are?  I also said MongoDB.  You should have enough to take a baby step forward with those.

Answer (score 0):

I've come to the conclusion, after a LOT of research, that @duffymo's answer is hinting in the right direction. For the benefit of other n00bs like me, here's the conclusion I've drawn:

Many open source search engine server apps are out there to install for free. Lucene was the first I had ever heard of them, but others do exist and I think my favourite at the moment is Sphinx. As far as I can tell, the 'indexer' that @duffymo mentions is built into it. I have learnt that the indexer is the program that will examine my database for keywords and will automatically keep a record of which results should be returned for different input queries. I have also now learnt that the terminology for the behaviour I was looking for (and which Sphinx has) is 'stemming'. I'm still not sure what role a parser plays in all this...

A more basic approach would be to use SQL itself. Whilst I was already aware of the most basic of these (ie. using the LIKE keyword with 'wildcards'), I also discovered something a little more powerful: natural language / full-text search. For anyone not interested in installing a server app, I recommend you look this up.

Also, I see no reason why I would need to use NoSQL instead of SQL (as @duffymo has suggested), and so I'm going to stick with SQL for the moment (at least until I come across some good entry-level books to learn NoSQL from). Furthermore, I have very little intention to learn relational algebra until I know *why* I should and *how* it would be useful. The message here is that other beginners shouldn't be off-put by these things, as I don't think Sphinx requires any knowledge of them.

Comment: relational algebra is the basis for relational databases - which are optimal when you design them with the basic principles in mind.  So to be good at SQL - fundamentally, you should be good at relational algebra.

Comment: like keywords are pretty insufficient for proper stemming searches - in a SQL solution, you will need to come up with a robust full text search probably based on your own tables and data parsing.

Answer (score 0):

while I like @duffymo's answer, I will also suggest you research SPARQL and the wordnet project for your semantic equivalence questions.

If you choose Oracle, you can use the spatial option triple store to implement the SPARQL endpoint and do some very nice seaching like your css = Cascading Style Sheet example.